# build failed due to wrong jvm target

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, jvm

With Gradle 8 and Kotlin 1.8 I got an error when compiling

```
compileDebugJavaWithJavac' task (current target is 1.8) and 'kaptGenerateStubsDebugKotlin' task (current target is 17) 
jvm target compatibility should be set to the same Java version.
```

This is a multi module project, and the problem only occur to this module. But, this module also using same JVM target and compatibility target. But how does this happened?

Here is my Gradle for this module:

```groovy
plugins {
    id 'com.android.library'
    alias libs.plugins.kotlin.android.plugin
    alias libs.plugins.kotlin.kapt.plugin
    alias libs.plugins.dagger.hilt.module.plugin
}

android {
    namespace 'com.lelestacia.network'
    compileSdk 33

    defaultConfig {
        minSdk 24

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        consumerProguardFiles "consumer-rules.pro"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to configure kapt to generate Java17 Java stubs in Android Gradle build file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75109742/how-to-configure-kapt-to-generate-java17-java-stubs-in-android-gradle-build-file) I know you want to do it the other way, but the answer is the same

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm getting similar error. These processes worked for me.

`build.gradle(:project)`

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '8.0.0' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '8.0.0' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.8.10' apply false
}
```

`build.gradle(:app)`

```
...
compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '17'
    }
...
```

Android Studio - Gradle Projects

[image]

Answer (score 7):

You need specify module compile version's compatibility to be appropriate to kaptGenerateStubsDebugKotlin.

```
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
}
```

But with latest versions of Gradle it is not enough, so you have to use Gradle JVM toolchain feature. Add the following config to android section of your module's gradle file

```
java {
   toolchain {
       languageVersion.set(JavaLanguageVersion.of(17))
   }
}
kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = '17'
}
```

Comment: This worked for me, but I did not need the java/toolchain entry.

Comment: THis is downgrading the java version no?

Comment: JavaVersion.Version_1_8 corresponds JDK 8, meanwhile JavaVersion.Version_17 corresponds JDK 17. So it isn't downgrading

Answer (score 0):

Besides the appropriate `build.gradle` settings mentioned already.

If you run a gradle task from cli, gradle checks what the environments java path is set to. You may need to update your computer's java path.

If you run a gradle task from android studio, gradle checks what Android Studio's JDK is set to. You may need to update your IDE's jdk.

Comment: I execute build on build server from CLI. My app is set to JDK 17 and my build server's JAVA_HOME is set to JDK 19. I cannot change JAVA_HOME on build server (it's required for building other apps). Is there a workaround for me?

Comment: I won't be able to give you a good answer on that, but I hope you find what you're looking for. I'd be interested to know if you find a solution (or have already found one).

Comment: I ended up using JDK 19 for my app as well because I did not find other solution

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that still hasn't figured it out, my issue was that ALL modules need to have this version set. The project I am working on has 5 modules and one of their build.gradle files didn't have

```
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
}
```

In fact, it didn't have any compileOptions block at all. So I am guessing it was defaulting to an earlier version. Once I added that into the final build.gradle file everything built correctly.