# org.gradle.api.GradleException: 'compileDebugJavaWithJavac' task (current target is 1.8)

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I searched about the following error a lot.

```
Caused by: org.gradle.api.GradleException: 'compileDebugJavaWithJavac' task (current target is 1.8) and 'kaptGenerateStubsDebugKotlin' task (current target is 17) jvm target compatibility should be set to the same Java version.
```

All answers that I found were I should update the following value equal to the Java version. in my case `17`

```
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
```

```
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
```

Another question raised in my mind was why the new Android project values are 1.8 while the application works correctly.

I created a new project and found the reason.
The following condition is the reason for the error.
1- Gradle version is 8.0 or above
2- The Java version is more than 1.8
3- Kapt is added to the Build.Gradle plugins

The application faced an error while all the above conditions were true.
My question is Why?

Comment: The project template was designed to work with older Android Studio that had java 8 build-in. The new AS comes with Java 17. Kapt plugin uses different setting for java version. This may be related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75158443/4758618

Comment: I think this https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support could help answer your question.